# Does the Legendre-Hadamard condition imply a generalized Gårding inequality?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde

For simplicity, we restrict to constant coefficients. Let $A^{ij}_{ab} \in \mathbb{R}$, $1 \le i, j \le n$ and $1 \le a, b\le m$, satisfy the Legendre-Hadamard condition:
$$
A^{ij}_{ab}\xi_i\xi_jv^av^b \ge \lambda |\xi|^2|v|^2
$$
for some $\lambda > 0$ and any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

It is straightforward to use the Fourier transform to prove that there exists $c > 0$ such that given any $u \in C^\infty_0(B,\mathbb{R}^m)$,
$$
\int_{B} A^{ij}_{ab}\partial_iu^a\partial_ju^b \ge c\int_B |\partial u|^2.
$$
If the (stronger) Legendre condition
$$
A^{ij}_{ab}p_i^ap_j^b \ge \lambda\sum_{i,a}(p_i^a)^2
$$
for any $p_i^a \in \mathbb{R}$ holds, it is easy to use an extension operator to extend the inequality to any function $u \in C^\infty(\overline{B},\mathbb{R}^m)$.

Question: Does the Legendre-Hadamard condition imply a Gårding inequality of the form
$$
\int_{B} A^{ij}_{ab}\partial_iu^a\partial_ju^b \ge \int_B c|\partial u|^2 - c'|u|^2,
$$
for any $u \in C^\infty(\overline{B},\mathbb{R}^m)$? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: The key test case is probably when the ball $B$ is replaced by a half-space (and the lower order term is deleted); this test case has to be true if your question is to hold, by a scaling argument.  One should probably try a reflection argument in the half-space case; if it works, it should be adaptable to the ball setting.

Comment: Terry, thanks! Obvious after you said it. I'll try that.

Comment: In the half-space case one can also try taking a Fourier transform in the tangential directions, this appears to reduce things to a 1D problem on a half-line which should be directly solvable.  (To adapt this sort of method to the ball though may require some Fourier integral operators or something to replace the Fourier transform.)

Comment: Terry, perhaps I'm trying to do the reflection too naively but I can't get it to work. If I reflect the function about the hyperplane $x^n = 0$, then the argument seems to work only if $A^{in}_{ab} = 0$ for $1 \le i \le n-1$. Or if $u=0$ along the hyperplane.

Comment: In addition to my answer: the integral inequality, when stated for fields vanishing at the boundary, is called *quasi-convexity*. When stated for every fields, John Ball call it quasi-convexity *up to the boundary*.

Comment: Terry, thanks again for your help. As Denis' answer shows, the tangential Fourier transform does indeed provide the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is **No**, and this is an interesting question.

As Terry Tao commented, the test case is when $B$ is replaced by a half-space $H$, so let us consider the latter case for a moment and fields $u$ with compact support in $\bar B$ (i.e. not vanishing at the boundary).

Because $H$ is dilation invariant, a Garding inequality implies actually an inequality of the form
$$
\int_H A^{ij}_{ab}\partial_iu^a\partial_ju^b \ge c\int_H |\partial u|^2.
$$
So we are led to the question whether such an inequality holds true or not.
I analysed this problem in my paper "Second-order initial-boundary value problems of variational type". *J. of Functional Analysis*, **236** (2006), pp 409-446.
The existence of such an inequality is equivalent to a Lopatinskii-type property, which can be expressed in terms of a Lopatinskii determinant associated with the symbol $A$. The technique uses a Fourier transform in the $n-1$ coordinates along the boundary. You will find in Section 6 examples and counter-examples.

I do not resist to give the following counter-example: take the linear isotropic elasticity, satisfying the Legendre-Hadamard condition. It has two wave velocities, $c_S$ for shear (transverse) waves and $c_P$ for pressure (longitudinal) waves. In real media, we have $c_S<c_P$. However, L.-H. does not prevent from the possibility of $c_P<c_S$, in which case the inequality above does not hold. Actually, the lack of inequality reveals the ill-posedness of the Initial-boundary-value problem in the half-space when the boundary condition is Neumann-type (here free displacement).

Now, when the inequality above holds true in every half-space, I proved that the Garding inequality holds true in bounded domains. It is not contained in my article (it was in the submission) because it is essentially an exercise.

[Link to my JFA paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123606000978). The main result is Theorem 3.5. Isotropic elasticity is treated in Paragraph 6.3, see Theorem 6.2.

Comment: Many thanks! I haven't had a chance to study your paper carefully, but it looks good. I've learned that elliptic systems of PDE's can have much more subtle behavior than scalar elliptic PDE's.

Comment: Yes indeed. There is also an old paper, with too a wide scope to answer to your question, by Agmon, Douglis & Nirenberg. There is also the seminal work of Lopatinskii.

Comment: @Denis: for those of us less well-versed, can you indicate which of the works of Lopatinskii is the seminal one you refer to? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Willy. Lopatinskii worked on elliptic equations and systems, as did later ADN. Actually, I am not an elliptic, but an hyperbolic PDEist. Nevertheless, Lopatinskii's idea applies also to the hyperbolic context, as quoted by R. Sakamoto and H.-O. Kreiss in the early 70'. It is amazing that when a conference was organized in Russia for the Lopatinskii's centenary, no hyperbolist was invited ! All this to say that I don't have a precise answer to your query. Sometimes, for hyperbolic boundary value problem, we speak of a KSL condition, instead of just a Lopatinskii condition.

Comment: **Complement about elasticity**: genuine materials obey to nonlinear equations, because linearity is not compatible with objectivity and the fact that energy tends to infinity as $\det\nabla u\rightarrow0^+$. It might be possible that for some state, quasi-convexity holds in the classical sense, but not "up to the boundary". Such states can happen in the bulk of the elastic body, if it is suitably deformed ; but they cannot be observed on its surface, where they would be Hadamard unstable.

Answer (score 4):

Gui-Qiang Chen suggested me to look at your question.

I assume that your notation $\partial u$ means the gradient $\nabla u$. In the following I use $\bar\partial u$ to denote the standard first order operator for complex functions.

There is another simple counter-example in the $2\times 2$ case. Consider the convex functional
$I(u)=\int_B|\bar\partial u|^2dx$ for $u=u_1+iu_2$ and write the quadratic form in terms of
$u_1$ and $u_2$. Since $|\bar\partial u|^2=|P_{E_{\bar\partial}}\nabla u|^2$, where $P_{E_{\bar\partial}}$ is the orthogonal projection to the subspace of anti-conformal matrices and $\nabla u$ is the gradient of $(u_1,u_2)$, we have, for every rank-one matrix $\xi\otimes\eta$ that  $|P_{E_{\bar\partial}} \xi\otimes\eta|^2=|\xi|^2|\eta|^2/2$. It is easy to see that the corresponding coefficient tensor $A$ satisfies the strong L-H condition. However, if one takes any holomorphic function $u$, then $I(u)=0$. This leads to
easy counter-examples for every fixed pair of constants $c>0$ and $c^\prime>0$, e.g. $u_n=e^{nz}$. This type of constructions by using subspaces of conformal and anti-conformal matrices in the space of $2\times 2$ real matrices are commonly used in the vectorial calculus of variations related to quasiconvexity and material microstructure.

If $A$ is not a constant tensor, say,
$A\in L^\infty$, even under the homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition, Garding's inequality fails in general. I constructed such an example some years ago: `A counterexample in the theory of coerciveness for elliptic systems. J. Partial Differential Equations 2 (1989), no. 3, 79–82 (MR1026095)'.  I also have some recent results on the so-called universal coercivity problem: 'On coercivity and regularity for linear elliptic systems.  Calc. Var. PDEs 40 (2011), no. 1-2, 65–97 (MR2745197)'.

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed a nice and simple counterexample.